# Scenario when we may be needing @Configurable in spring?

Tags: spring

I have question about the need of using `@configurable`. I have gone through the [blog](http://aredko.blogspot.in/2011/02/using-configurable-in-spring-framework.html) that explains how to use `@configurable`. But the question that comes to my mind is, what can be the scenario when we need to use `@configurable`. I can think of two scenarios where it can be useful

1. In a legacy project, when we are already making any bean with new operator and we want to make it spring managed.
2. In a new project, we want to enforce that even if developer makes the bean with new operator, still it is spring managed.

Otherwise for new beans we can always declare them in applicationContext.xml and I do not see any need to declare them `@configurable`.

Please let me know if above understanding  is correct or if I am missing something.

**UPDATE:-** Basically as per my understanding configurable is generally used to inject dependency when creating the object with new operator. But why would i be creating the object with new operator when i am using spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Configurable` annotation is meant for injecting dependencies in [`domain-driven`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) applications. That means, in such applications, the domain objects interact with each other to perform a certain operation.

Take the following example:

In an invoicing application, the `Invoice` class provides a constructor to create it, then it has methods to validate, and finally persist it. Now, to persist the invoice, you need a `DAO` implementation available within the invoice. This is a dependency you would like to be injected or located. With Spring's `@Configurable`, whenever an invoice is created using the `new` operator, the appropriate DAO implementation will get injected and can be used for all persist operations.

I had a more realtime scenario where I used `@Configurable` annotation as described [here](http://vikdor.blogspot.in/2012/08/using-configurable-to-inject-resources.html).

Comment: Question is why would i create the invoice object with new operator when i am using spring. Ideally i would create any object from spring factory not new. so in that case we won't be needing configurable  annotation. Right?

Comment: Assuming a user action triggers creation of invoice, how would you create an object from spring factory at that time? declaring invoice as a prototype bean and getting an instance of this bean from the factory? That is not right way to use a DI framework. Moreover, your domain objects don't expose setters to each attribute inside which is against the abstraction principle. These domain objects are not beans in any sense.